# Why are source files from other projects being included in artifacts?

Tags: teamcity

I'm building a solution in teamcity that includes 3 TFS source roots. The sln I'm building includes other projects that are also projects in other solutions in those source trees. The artifacts generated from my build include the source trees from other projects in those source trees (!?). I don't understand what's making that happen. The source files for the projects I'm actually building don't get copied. I've set my "Artifact Path" setting to be empty, which I would think would mean I'd get no artifacts. But no dice... I get the source tree from the projects that I'm not building.

Anyone know why this happens and/or how to make it stop?

Comment: Could you share what your actual settings are? It's pretty hard to guess what's going wrong. If your artifact paths is truly empty, then you shouldn't get any artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, fixed it! Thanks @coderdennis for confirming that I shouldn't be seeing artifacts. Knowing that, I went through and disabled all build steps and then enabled them one by one.. no artifacts were generated until I got to the last build step (always the last step...), which is a "NuGet Pack" runner type. For whatever reason, I had the "Output Directory" setting set to "%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%" and the "Publish created packages to build artifacts" checkbox checked. Oops.